# Found the synthetic property @onMainContentChange. Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I have two modules: AppModule and AFModule:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
... 
...
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
...
... 
@NgModule({

    imports: [
        ...
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        ...

    ],
    exports: [
        ...
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        AppHomeComponent,
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true },
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true },
        InternationalizationService,
        fakeBackendProvider
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { };
```

**af.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AFLeftMenuComponent } from "@/modules/af/components/left-menu";
import { AFComponent } from './af.component';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SidenavService } from '@/shared/_services/sidenav.service'
import {

    MatSelectModule,
    ...
    MatSidenavModule,
} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({

    imports: [
        ...
        MatSelectModule,
        CommonModule,
        MatSidenavModule,
        ...
    ],
    exports: [
        ....
    ],
    declarations: [
        AFComponent,
        AFLeftMenuComponent,
        ....
    ],
    entryComponents: [],
    providers: [
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true },
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true },
        SidenavService,
    ],
    bootstrap: [AFComponent]
})
export class AFModule { };
```

**af.component.html** :

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
      <mat-sidenav #leftSidenav mode="side" opened>
            <af-left-menu></af-left-menu>
        </mat-sidenav>
        <mat-sidenav-content [@onMainContentChange]="onSideNavChange ? 'open': 'close'">
           <div class="main_content">
                <div style="padding: 20px">
                     Your content
                </div>
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>
           </div>
        </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Then, it is showing the error like this: 
[image]

If I import the BrowserAnimationModule to the **af.module.ts**, It would show error: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import CommonModule instead.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for bothering you guys, I found the root cause after two days struggling.

I made a mistake, I didn't add the onMainContentChange animation to af.component.ts.
It is working well now.